# Jabref and lyx: "selective" pushing

Tags: lyx

When trying to insert citations into lyx from a `.bib` file generated with jabref. Only a subset of citation (5! out of 20 in jabref) show up in the citation selection menu from lyx.

Using:

- lyx 2.0.2
- jabref 2.7b
- ubuntu 12.04LTS

lyxpipe is set up in both programs under `~/.lyxpipe`

Answer (score 1):

Found at least a workaround.

reseting the lyxpipe to  ~/.lyx/lyxpipe does not really do the trick.

my workaround is to create several sane small .bib files using a text editor and add them to the lyx citation list.

for reasons unknown to me, some bib entries break the lyxpipe. If these are put at the end of each .bib file things seem to work.

Cheers :-)